# mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql

I've this problem when I'm trying to run my PHP MySQL script. When I try to run my .php file this is what I get.

**A PHP Error was encountered**

Severity: Warning

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be
>   made because the target machine actively refused it.

```
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
```

Line Number: 135

Backtrace:

> File: C:\wamp\www\acc\index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsUOi.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add some code context so we can see what's going on please?

Comment: I can see in your image, you are using a class to determine the connection attributes, can you add how these are set, where and the full class please? (Obviously without sensitive data)

Comment: At first sight, you are connecting to machine which not listen on that port. Verify that hostname/port combination is correct (eg. using telnet or nmap)

Answer (score 0):

this is mysql error change your msql port to 3306